# How to select value of a column and add to a list?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, windows-phone

I have a [Table] SearchHistory with some [Column] such as ByAny, ByTitle, ByAuthor, ByGenre. I want to select all value of ByAny into a list or collection used for ItemsSource in my Listbox. If can, i need to select distinct value. please help me...thanks

Comment: Hmm... Someone did before you added this comment. But the question is not clear, so you first have to help yourself. Where is the part that should add new items to the collection? What makes this harder than `Clear` and `Add`?

Comment: It gets worse with each edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the items and add the new ones:

```
public void LoadSearchHistory()
{
    var load1 = (from SearchHistory s in BookDB.SearchHistorys select s.ByAny).Distinct(_ => _.ByAny);
    DataSearch.Items.Clear();
    DataSearch.Items.AddRange(load1);
}
```

Comment: Please check again :( Datasearch is of Table "SearchHistory" not of "Book" :( i got mistake

Comment: ByAny just is a Column in SearchHistory table. I want to select all value of ByAny in SearchHistory table and get distinct value

Comment: What type is it? your ObservableCollection is of type SearchHistory. It can only contain SearchHistory items.

Comment: I create the SearchHistory table with these column: ByAny | ByTitle | ByAuthor | ByEditor. After I adding data into the table. i want to select all value of ByAny